# How to stop textarea tag from translating numbers

Tags: html, laravel, textarea, translation, multilingual

I have a bilingual website with English for the user side and Persian for the admin panel. Now when I create articles in English in the admin panel it translates numbers to Persian and it saves it in Persian format to database. How can I prevent it?

A few things I've tried are putting the "lang" attribute on Textarea tag and also on a span tag wrapping Textarea, making Textarea rtl.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with coding. It is a just a textarea in a form and I don't make any manual changes when saving the contents. I'm using `App::setLocale('en')` in the routing file for user routings and `App::setLocale('fa')` for admin side routings.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It was because of the font I've been using.

I changed it to IRANSans and the problem disappeared.